# Delete First line of a file

Tags: shell-script, sed, ksh

How can I delete the first line of a file and keep the changes?

I tried this but it erases the whole content of the file.

```
$sed 1d file.txt > file.txt
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The reason file.txt is empty after that command is the order in which the shell does things. The first thing that happens with that line is the redirection. The file "file.txt" is opened and truncated to 0 bytes. After that the sed command runs, but at the point the file is already empty.

There are a few options, most involve writing to a temporary file.

```
sed '1d' file.txt > tmpfile; mv tmpfile file.txt # POSIX
sed -i '1d' file.txt # GNU sed only, creates a temporary file

perl -ip -e '$_ = undef if $. == 1' file.txt # also creates a temporary file
```

Comment: With BSD `sed`, you may use `sed -i .bak '1d' file.txt`.

Comment: is there a way that does not include temp file? Anyway, this will do the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kickass13 possibly using a text editor such as `ed`.

Comment: The `ed` command would be: `printf "%s\n" 1d w q | ed file.txt` (I heart ed)

Comment: Can anyone point me to how to do this for a set of files found with 'find', as in https://superuser.com/questions/112078/delete-matching-files-in-all-subdirectories ?

Comment: @jonayreyes `-exec sed -i '1d' {} \;`

Comment: thanks @jordanm but I don't know where to place the file names (twice) in the expression. I get it's something like `find . -name "myfiles*" -exec sed '1d' xxxxxxxxx > tmpfile; mv tmpfile xxxxxxxx`. Do I have to put two blocks of `{}` there?

Comment: @jordanm I link `sed -i '1d' file.txt`, but if I want to delete first `100` line. `sed -i '100d' file.txt` does'nt work.

Comment: @alhelal yes, that will only delete line 100.

Comment: @alhelal type `sed -i 1,100d file.txt`

Answer (score 212):

An alternative very lightweight option is just to 'tail' everything but the first line (this can be an easy way to remove file headers generally):

```
# -n +2 : start at line 2 of the file.
tail -n +2 file.txt > file.stdout
```

Following @Evan Teitelman, you can:

```
tail -n +2 file.txt | sponge file.txt
```

To avoid a temporary file.  Another option might be:

```
echo "$(tail -n +2 file.txt)" > file.txt
```

And so forth.  Testing last one:

```
[user@work ~]$ cat file.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5

[user@work ~]$ echo "$(tail -n +2 file.txt)" > file.txt
[user@work ~]$ cat file.txt
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
[user@work ~]$
```

Oops we lost a newline (per @1_CR comment below), try instead:

```
printf "%s\n\n" "$(tail -n +2 file.txt)" > file.txt

[user@work ~]$ cat file.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5

[user@work ~]$ printf '%s\n\n' "$(tail -n +2 file.txt)" > file.txt
[user@work ~]$ cat file.txt
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5  

[user@work ~]$
```

Coming back to sed, try:

```
printf '%s\n\n' "$(sed '1d' file.txt)" > file.txt
```

or perhaps

```
echo -e "$(sed '1d' file.txt)\n" > file.txt
```

To avoid side effects.

Comment: I've just tried it on my Fedora system and the output is above.  You are correct - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The `tail` trick worked for me (took less than 3 seconds on a 130mb file). Thanks!

Comment: `echo "$(tail -n +2 file.txt)" > file.txt` is the perfect answer.

Comment: Thank you! echo "$(tail -n +2 file.txt)" > file.txt works for me just like a charm!

Comment: The `echo -e` answer has the side effect of replacing "\n" literals in the file with actual new lines

Comment: Note that, if you dont use ´"´ in ´echo "$(tail -n +2 file.txt)"´, it put all in a single line.

Answer (score 23):

This topic is interest, so I test the benchmark in 3 ways:

1. `sed '1d' d.txt > tmp.txt`
2. `tail -n +2 d.txt > tmp.txt`
3. `sed -i '1d' d.txt`

Note that target `d.txt` is 5.4GB file

Get the result :

---

```
run 1 : sed '1d' d.txt > r1.txt
14s
run 2 : tail -n +2 d.txt > r2.txt
20s
run 3 : sed -i '1d' d.txt
88s
```

---

Conclusion : It seems below be the quickest way:

**`sed '1d' file.txt > tmpfile; mv tmpfile file.txt`**

Comment: Your `sed '1d' d.txt` method did not include (or so it seems by reading your tests) the `mv` command. In my tests on FreeBSD with a 20MB file the `sed -i` was the quickest.

Answer (score 18):

Also take a look at `sponge` from
[`moreutils`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/). `sponge` soaks in data from
standard input until standard input's writing end closes before writing to a
file. It is used like so:

```
sed '1d' file.txt | sponge file.txt
```

Answer (score 10):

`ex` can be used for true in-place editing <strike>that does not involve a temp file</strike>

```
ex -c ':1d' -c ':wq' file.txt
```

Comment: ex does use a temp file. `strace -e open ex -c ':1d' -c ':wq' foo`. ex truncates the original file with the temp file, where as GNU sed's -i option overwrites the original with the temp file. I am not sure how BSD's sed works.

Comment: @llua, you are right. I noticed that too, but later

Answer (score 5):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -s -c '1d|x' file.txt
```

1. `1` find first line
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score 4):

The shortest and simplest way to delete the first line from a file using `sed` is:

```
$ sed -i -n -e '2,$p' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use vim to do this:

```
vim -u NONE +'1d' +wq! /tmp/test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print}' file.txt > file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will remove 1 line and save as "file.txt".

```
sed '1d' file.txt  > /tmp/file.txt && mv /tmp/file.txt file.txt || rm -f /tmp/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**To delete a particular line in file:**

1. Delete first line

   ```
   sed '1d' file
   ```
2. Delete first and third line

   ```
   sed '1d3d' file
   ```

**To delete a charecter in a line**

1. Delete First two charters in lin

   ```
   sed 's/^..//' file
   ```
2. Delete last two chrecters in line

   ```
   sed 's/..$//' file
   ```
3. Delete blank line

   ```
   sed '/^$/d' file
   ```

Comment: A longer answer to "delete the first line of a file and keep the changes": Read the file while counting and discard just the first :

counter=0 ; while read line; do [ $counter != 0 ] && echo $line ; counter=$(( counter+1 )) ; done < ./test > /tmp/test ; mv /tmp/test ./test

I can't find a way of avoiding a temp file, the closest is as above creating the output in /tmp which is not meaningfully different to a temp fle.